# Hessian: Java Client can't connect to php server

Tags: java, php, hessian

I am using Hessian Binary Protocol. It works fine when

## CASE I:

- Server
- -- Java
- Client
- -- Java
- -- PHP

## CASE II:

- Server
- -- PHP
- Client
- -- PHP

But it throws exception

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL
```

when

## CASE III:

- Server
- -- PHP
- Client
- -- JAVA

I have googled a lot & found this https://code.google.com/p/hessianphp/issues/detail?id=20

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hessian** uses **v1** as default. It will give you error in the case you're using. However, **HessianProxyFactory** can be easily switched to **v2** mode,  like I demonstrate here in the following sample code:

```
HessianProxyFactory factory = new HessianProxyFactory();
factory.setHessian2Request(true);
// Do something
```

Source: [Hessdroid](https://code.google.com/p/hessdroid/wiki/faq)

Hope that will work for you!